# ODE $y'-xe^y=2e^y$ using $e^{\int P(x)dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked a student how to solve the following problem.

> Solve for the general solution to the differential equation  $y'-xe^y=2e^y$

My first instinct told me that this was a problem that could be solved using

$$e^{\int{-x}dx}=u(x)$$

and by multiplying it on both sides we could solve for $y$ as

$$y=\frac{1}{u(x)}\int u(x)2e^ydx$$

Nevertheless as you can see instantly, I noticed that the original equation was not in the form of

$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$

so I tried the following transformation.

By letting $e^y=v$, $y'=\frac{v'}{v}$ so

$$v'-xv^2=2v$$

which looks a lot closer to the form that I wanted to have and maybe later I would be able to solve for $y$.

I spent about 30 min until I noticed that the separation of variables were much more efficient and easier.

However, I am thinking (and also curious) that the $e^{\int p(x) dx}$ method should also work; it's just that I am not putting it in the right position.

Would someone be able to show me that it would actually work?

Comment: Just glancing at this. The basic method seems to be the use of an integrating factor, which for linear equations has that form or similiar. I would check for your equation, how a proper integrating factor might look.

Comment: I don't know how much this could help but if you define $x+2=t$ and $e^y=z$, the equation becomes simple and separable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
y' - x e^y = 2e^y
\\
\iff y'e^{-y} = x + 2
$$